# Exact solution to equation

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to find out how to get some form of exact nonzero solution with isolated x for the equation $x^2 = \sin x$. I am pretty sure my TI 89 is using Taylor series expansions to solve this because it will not give anything but a decimal approximation. I am thinking Euler's formula needs to be used in some capacity but I have tried several things and cannot find a way to isolate $x$.

Comment: What makes you think that the unique positive solution to this is actually expressible in some finite form other than "the unique positive solution to $x^2 = \sin x$" ?  Chances are very good that $x$ is not rational, for instance.

Comment: It is not possible to explicitly isolate for $x$ in this case.

Comment: That makes sense, it is most likely irrational. In that case, what would be the best approach for solving this without a calculator?

Comment: Draw a graph of $y = x^2$ and $y = \sin x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a graph of $y = x^2$ and $y = \sin x$. Obviously x = 0 is a solution, the other solution is near $x = 1$. You can then use any numerical methods to get close to the actual solution for the one near $x = 1$. Once you have imagined or drawn the graph, you know that these are the only two solutions. 3 iterations of a numerical method gave me $0.876$ as the other solution